# how to invoke button command with enter key

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In tkinter, when a button has the focus, you can press the space bar to execute the command associated with that button.  I'm trying to make pressing the Enter key do the same thing.  I'm certain I've done this in the past, but I can't find the code, and what I'm doing now isn't working.  I'm using python 3.6.1 on a Mac.

Here is what I've tried

```
self.startButton.bind('<Return>', self.startButton.invoke)
```

Pressing the Enter key has no effect, but pressing the space bar activates the command bound to `self.startButton`.  I've tried binding to `<KeyPress-KP_Enter>` with the same result.

I also tried just binding to the command I want to execute:

```
self.startButton.bind('<Return>', self.start)
```

but the result was the same.

**EDIT**

Here is a little script that exhibits the behavior I'm talking about.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk() 
def start():
    print('started')
    startButton.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
    clearButton.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)

def clear():
    print('cleared')
    clearButton.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
    startButton.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)    

frame = tk.Frame(root)
startButton = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Start', command = start, state=tk.NORMAL)
clearButton = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Clear', command = clear, state = tk.DISABLED)
startButton.bind('<Return>', start) 
startButton.pack()
clearButton.pack()
startButton.focus_set()  
frame.pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

In this case, it works when I press space bar and fails when I press Enter.  I get an error message when I press Enter, saying that there an argument was passed, but none is required.  When I change the definition of to take dummy argument, pressing Enter works, but pressing space bar fails, because of a missing argument.

I'm having trouble understanding how wizzwizz4's answer gets both to work.  Also, I wasn't seeing the error message when I pressed Enter in my actual script, but that's way too long to post.

** EDIT AGAIN **

I was just overlooking the default value of None in Mike-SMT's script.  That makes things plain.

Comment: The way you use bind should work -- that's exactly how you do it. Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates what you've tried.

Comment: @BryanOakley It's a subtle error if it's what I think it is.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a proper example. The OP says that pressing the space bar works, which means that the button has focus. I should have said in my earlier comment that the bind would work, _but only if you take into account that the function will be passed a parameter that needs to be accounted for_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `self.startButton.bind('<Return>', self.start)` should work fine as long as compensate for the `event` that the bind will send to the function/method.

Here is a simple example that will work with the enter key as long as the button has focus.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

def do_something(event=None):
    print("did something!")

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Do something", command=do_something)
btn.pack()
btn.bind("<Return>", do_something)
#root.bind("<Return>", do_something) will work without the button having focus.

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The default value for event was what I kept overlooking.  Now this works just as I want, once I give `btn` the focus so that spacebar works too,.

Comment: @saulspatz yes you will have to manage your events for any `bind()`'s you need to set. Either by telling your function to accept an event argument or by using a lambda like wizzwizz4 used.

Answer (score 3):

This only works when the button has keyboard focus. Also, an argument representing the event object is passed to the callable provided. The former doesn't seem to be the problem, so try:

```
self.startButton.bind('<Return>', lambda e: self.startButton.invoke())
```

Comment: Where this does work I think its a bit overkill with the lambda. A simple bind function with a call to the same command will work fine.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I could argue that yours requires the programmer to restate the arguments that should be passed to the function in the event of a button press, since it will no longer use those that would have been provided with `command=`, leaving yours simpler in one specific case but more complicated in all others.

Comment: However my method does not create a new function in memory. Though a small impact your example "cost" more. Really thought within a GUI like this it is unlikely that you will need to worry about optimizing everything.

Comment: @saulspatz If this solved your problem, consider accepting it by clicking the tick underneath the voting buttons. That'll mark it as Accepted, mark the question as Answered and give me a nice 15 rep bonus.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm still trying to understand the other answer.

Comment: The only change in the other answer is `event=None` added to the arguments list, which means that the function can be called with either zero or one arguments without Python raising a `TypeError`. It's got a small runtime saving but that's compared to the cost of harder to read code, and Python's not the fastest thing in the first place.